# Wordpress Url Rewrite Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My goal is to add `/?lang=it` to every WordPress url.

For example,
let `example.com` automatically redirect to `example.com/?lang=it`

and let `example.com/something` redirect to `example.com/something/?lang=it`

But this should not include `example.com/wp-login.php` and `example.com/wp-admin/` folder.

What should I add/modify to the default WordPress htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you define a rewriting rule for that and add two conditions for the two exceptions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?lang=it [END]
```

Those rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). You always should prefer the first option unless you have no access to the configuration (read: really cheap web space provider).

In case you received a server internal error (http status 500) using that rule set then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will find a definite hint on the unsupported `[END]` flag in that case in your http servers error log file. You should either upgrade the server in that case or use the `[L]` flag instead, it probably will work similar here, though that depends on the rest of your setup.

Comment: Thank you. Tried your code but it does not redirect.  I noticed along with wordpress files, there's a .fast-cgi-bin folder. So its different from apache? Also from my end, I can switch to different php version.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. Also I do not see a connection to how you execute php, as fastCGI container or as apache module.

Comment: "it does not redirect" is a bit vague. You will have to dig deeper to find out _why_ that won't get applied. 1. find out if those rules are interpreted _at all_ , so check your http servers error log file while making requests, especially a test where you place a definite syntax error in that .htaccess file. If that does not give a hint you will need to enable rewrite logging and check what your rewriting engine actually does.

Comment: Hi, I am able to ssh into the root but unable to open the etc and var/log/ folder. It restricts a certain commands I believe. Sudo command is not supported as it outputs command not found error. I tried su myusername and su root, it does ask me input invisible password but its Permission denied and Authentication failure. I am not able to chmod those folders.

Comment: This is the default htaccess codes after I updated permalink

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Where should i insert these 3 lines , and in which order. I want to try one more time. Perhaps you can reorder the lines and modify and delete those causing conflicts.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?lang=it [END]

Comment: "does not redirect" means after I opened the website in a new browser. I clicked the homepage example.com, i clicked  example.com/post1/, and i clicked example.com/somethingnoneexistent/,    the browser address bar wont return the url i want.  ie attaching /?lang=it ,this snippet in the url end